# Why "Knit to pdf" in RMarkdown throws error?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have installed tinytex package in R. While using R Markdown, I can not knit to pdf, even though I can knit to html.

I have tried knit to html, that works. But knit to pdf shows error.

I get the following error message:

> Error: Failed to compile New_Rmamrkdown.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See New_Rmamrkdown.log for more info.
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.5.3
>   Execution halted

Comment: The output *before* that error message, in my experience, is usually what's more informative. Can you post more of the output?

Comment: ! fmtutil [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=pdflatex, skipped
! fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 0
! fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
! Running the command C:\Users\thispc\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe

! kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt

! The command name is C:\Users\thispc\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexfmt

Comment: Have you tried reinstaling TinyTeX with `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()`?

Answer (score 0):

It requires an additional third party software(latex), there are various softwares to do the task. Try this [miktex](https://miktex.org/). I tried in my Ubuntu OS with RStudio, it works good. Install this package, and please mention whether it works for you!