# RMarkdown: Not able to knit to pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have been using Rmarkdown for some months but suddenly I can't knit to pdf any longer, I installed the latest version of **rstudio** and **tinytex**, Yet it's not building pdf. What else can I do?.

Below is the error message:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ^^N (U+000E)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.


Try other LaTeX engines instead (e.g., xelatex) if you are using pdflatex. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-unicode.html
Error: LaTeX failed to compile Introduction-to-R-for-statistical-computing.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Introduction-to-R-for-statistical-computing.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

Comment: There are lots of problems with unescaped strings in LaTeX, you'll find similar errors at [tex.se] (e.g., [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=Package+inputenc+Error%3A+Unicode+character)). Either here or there, though, I don't know that we can really help without a reproducible question (i.e., spartan input Rmarkdown document that still produces this error).

Answer (score 0):

After I tried severally, I came across this `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()` from [Why "Knit to pdf" in RMarkdown throws error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57218756/why-knit-to-pdf-in-rmarkdown-throws-error?rq=1) today.
It works for me perfectly. The **pdf** was built with all my equations written in tex. Also document was knitted in **word** with all the statistical models. Thanks so much.